# Need reorder sort_column Yii2

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

I need to reorder the column `sort_order`.
It is, select the position where to allocate the category and 
recalculate the table.

For example, if I select category 3, insert at next and reorder sort_order.

I tried this code but something is wrong:

```
       public function actionUp($id) {
               $model = $this->loadModel($id);

                $prev = Category::find()
                ->andWhere(['<', 'sort_order', $model->sort_order])
                ->orderBy(['sort_order' => SORT_DESC])
                ->limit(1)->one();

                $current = $model->sort_order;
                $model->sort_order = $prev->sort_order;
                $prev->sort_order = $current->sort_order;

                $model->save();
                $prev->save();
                return $
        this->redirect(['index']);
       }
```

How I can reorder this column?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: $prev->sort_order = $current;

Comment: In this way, it works, until you reach the last position

Trying to get property of non-object
$current = $model->sort_order;
        $model->sort_order = $prev->sort_order;
        $prev->sort_order = $current;

And how to reorder the sort_order column?

Comment: I have provided a solution to the "non-object" issue below. I am not clear about the "how to reorder" question. How are you surfacing the data? Via Gridview? If so, it has a sort function. Alternatively you can orderBy Category as you have done in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public function actionUp($id, $newPosition=null) {
               $model = Category::findOne($id);
               if(!$model)
                  throw new UserException('We were unable to find a matching record');


                $prev = Category::find()
                ->andWhere(['<', 'sort_order', $model->sort_order])
                ->orderBy(['sort_order' => SORT_DESC])
                ->limit(1)->one();

                if($prev)
                  $prevOrder = $prev->sort_order;
                else    
                 $prevOrder = 0;

                 $currentOrder = $model->sort_order;

                 If($newPosition)
                       $model->sortOrder = $newPosition;
                 else 
                       $model->sort_order = $prevOrder;
            $prev->sort_order = $currentOrder;


                $model->save();
                $prev->save();
                return $this->redirect(['index']);
       }
```

Comment: Now happens this 

Creating default object from empty value

 $prev->sort_order = $currentOrder;

Gridview have sort order?

Comment: If you are trying to sort data then, yes, this is all handled by the DataProvider. None of what you are doing above is necessary.

Comment: Regarding the new error above: please provide code for $this->loadModel() function. It seems you are retuning a null. Ordinarily you should handle this via an exception.

Comment: it's working, thank you!
the loaded code
$model = $this->categories->get($id);

repository
  public function get($id): Category
    {
        if (!$category = Category::findOne($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException('Category is not found. ');
        }
        return $category;
    }

I have the problem only in the last position.

Comment: Your code is not entirely clear to me so I have made a modification to what I originally posted. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have this, in the Categoryservice 
 public function moveUp($id){

```
$model = $this->categories->get($id);

        $prev = Category::find()
            ->andWhere(['<', 'sort_order', $model->sort_order])
            ->orderBy(['sort_order' => SORT_DESC])
            ->limit(1)->one();

        if($prev)
            $prevOrder = $prev->sort_order;
        else
            $prevOrder = 0;

        $currentOrder = $model->sort_order;
        $model->sort_order = $prevOrder;
        $prev->sort_order = $currentOrder;


        $prev->save();
        $this->categories->save($model);
}
```

You were right, one of the categories did not have sort_order, it was null, and it gave the error.

I have one more question, how can it do the same but, when creating to choose where to position it?

Comment: could it work if I create a new category and insert on a specific position?

Comment: It’s hard to understand exactly what you are doing. But in any event you can surely assign whatever value you want to the sort order when you create the record?

Answer (score 0):

```
actionUp and Down work well, thank you very much 

And when I'm going to add a new category, how can I indicate the position, based o parent_id?

public function create(CategoryCreateForm $form): Category
    {
        $channel = Category::create(
            $form->parentId,
            $form->name,
            $form->code,
            $form->description
        );

        $category = $this->categories->get($form->parentId);

        $next = Category::find()
            ->andWhere(['<', 'sort_order', $category->sort_order])
            ->orderBy(['sort_order' => SORT_DESC])
            ->limit(1)->one();

        if ($next)
            $nexOrder = $next->sort_order;
        else
            $nexOrder = 0;
        $currentOrder = $category->parent_id;
        if ($newPosition)
            $category->parent_id =$newPosition;
        else
             $category->parent_id = $nexOrder;
        $next->sort_order = $currentOrder;

        $prev->save();
        $this->categories->save($category);
        return $category;

    }

It does not work this way, what is wrong.
```

Comment: There are a lot of problems ! Where does $newPosition come from?? There is no call to create it. $currentOrder = $category->sort_order;

Comment: The solution is $category->sort_order = Category::find()->max('sort_order') + 1;
to get next sort_order.

But how to position the category based in parent_id and reorder sort_order if is possible?

Something like NestedSetsBehavior whit lft, rgt, depth.